# Trying to read a Flux<DataBuffer> into a InputStream using a Piped Input/Output stream blocks and times out

Tags: java, spring, nio, project-reactor, reactor

I have a pipeline that streams DataBuffers for various types of files. Recently I noticed a combination of source & target that completely blocks, causing a timeout. I have narrowed it down to a InputStream source, and a target that performs `InputStream.readAllBytes()` or `IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream)` from Apache-Commons IO.

```java
@Test
public void testReadAllBytesFromInputStream() {
        Path p = testResources.resolve("file.txt");
        Flux<DataBuffer> buffer = DataBufferUtils.readInputStream(
                () -> new FileInputStream(p.toFile()), leakAwareDataBufferFactory, 512);
        byte[] bytes = getBytesfromFlux(buffer);
        assertTrue( bytes.length > 0);
}

public byte[] getBytesFromFile(Flux<DataBuffer> buffer) throws IOException {
        PipedOutputStream osPipe = new PipedOutputStream();
        PipedInputStream isPipe = new PipedInputStream(osPipe);
        DataBufferUtils.write(source, osPipe)
            .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
                try {
                    osPipe.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    //nothing
                }
                return Flux.error(throwable);
            }).doOnComplete(() -> {
                try {
                    osPipe.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    //nothing
                }
        }).subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer());
        return isPipe.readAllBytes();
}
```

Simply doing a blocking call and merging them in will not work, as it would wreck the performance of consumers that stream correctly.
When reading from a FileChannel, it does not block. Seems to be a blocking issue between the piped streams and the byte consumer.

Comment: `piped streams and` - Seems like you haven't finished a sentence...

Comment: THe piped streams should be handled in different threads.